# Delphi - Form Deactivate

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4

What is the difference when a form hides or when it deactivates ?
When hiding my main form I log the event to a database (as application start). So I was wondering when to do the logging: on hide event or deactivate ? When I deactivate the form,what exactly am I doing?

Comment: Deactivation means the form no longer being in the front. It is a consequence of your hiding active form (VCL tries to find and activate another form). If it was not active when you hide it, f.i., it wouldn't deactivate.  Log your event at application start if it is to indicate when the application is started.

Comment: I am just wondering if it is the same thing...Hiding my form causes it to deactivate so I can do the logging over there as well. or no ?Just tested it on deactivate event and it works just like on hide.

Comment: Of course. It's not the same thing, but they'll be pretty close..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`OnDeactivate` executes whenever your Form (or "Window") loses focus (such as when the user selects another window).
`OnHide` executes when you call `Visible := False` or `MyForm.Hide;`

There is no OnEvent method built into TForm for `OnMinimize` or `OnRestore`, but a quick Google search will yield great examples on how to implement them yourself.

Comment: When a form hides it looses focus too.Yes? So if I understand correctly, in my example, it is basically the same thing since I am hiding the main form and showing another one.

Comment: Hiding the Form won't necessarily cause it to lose focus, but if your next Form takes focus when it shows, that certainly will cause the first Form to lose focus.

Comment: Yes,exactly...I am doing Form3.Show; MainForm.Hide;So I can use both cases (on deactivate) or (onhide) basically as the same thing, since mainform is going to loose focus anyway ??

Comment: Your reasoning is incomplete: just because your form looses focus when it is hidden does not mean they are the same thing. There are plenty of situations where your form looses focus but is **not** hidden. You need both directions for equivalence.